# CS0019 C# Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'method group'

Tags: c#

I got the above error on assigning a value to a string variable strsql as below:

```cs
string strsql = dup + "', '" + transdate + "', '" + msgtime + "', '" + sender.ToUpper + "', '" + debitaccount + "', '" + msgsession + "'"
```

Comment: It should be `sender.ToUpper()`

Comment: It's because you wrote `sender.ToUpper`, which doesn't invoke the method. Instead use `sender.ToUpper()`

Answer (score 3):

The error is due to `sender.ToUpper` which is supposed to be `sender.ToUpper()` because its a method as show in the code below :

---

```
string strsql = dup + "', '" + transdate + "', '" + msgtime + "', '" + sender.ToUpper() + "', '" + debitaccount + "', '" + msgsession + "'";
```

Comment: Thank you it is working now

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer :) @MohamedRihan